Extracting a single screenshot from every video file in a folder with the file name embedded on the image
I would like to extract a single screenshot from every video file in a folder with the file name embedded in the screenshot, in Windows. Like this:
File: Coherence.mkv
Screenshot:

Result:

How can I do this for multiple files?

What did you try so far?

You can use ffmpeg to extract the screenshot and add a text caption - see answered ffmpeg extract screenshot question, add text question

Thank you @Kissaki for referring these posts to me. "add text question" is close to what I want to do but not quite, unless I missed something. They explain how to add text, but it is manually typed in the command line and I need somehow to grab each file name dynamically for each corresponding screenshot and I don't see any mention on how to achieve that. The first article you shared explains how to get a frame from a specific time only.

@RomeoNinov Given the fact that I have zero knowledge on the matter, all I could do was research and try to find answers online as well as go over the ffmpeg documentation. I wasn't able to find what I need, hence the reason I am here.

Oh, I am a bit familiar with ffmeg. I use it for very simple things such as reducing file size and generating thumbnails from videos, but that as far as I go. I figured ffmpeg would have the ability to do what I need but could not find the way.

@KenPino The two links I commented are two parts of what you need. For the file handling I don't think it's possible with ffmpeg alone, you didn't even specify an OS or otherwise how you would want to handle files. I would use Nushell, but that's not natively available on Windows nor Linux. There are too many options available, the field is too broad, which is why I did not post an answer. It wasn't even clear whether command line would be fine for you. If it is, and you declared the OS in your question, it would at least be obvious which shells were available by default.

I was posting the two links because they are useful to solving your task. @RomeoNinov asked what you tried so far, which would help. See also the guidance on asking (good, answerable) questions.

Right, thanks a lot for the help. I'll make sure to include the OS next time to make it understandable. And I did answer what I tried.

At what time should the screenshot be taken? For example if it is the first frame of the movie a lo of those screenshots probably be black....

I found a tool that does exactly what you need: Movie Print.

It might be very useful to include how this tool solves your problem, how to use it, and a link in your answer, rather than just a name, so the next person with the same problem can look at it and decide if this solves their problem

Please read How do I recommend software for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.
